# Как обработать ошибку в pyqt5?

Tags: pyqt5

Подскажите как правильно обработать ошибки try/except в pyqt5 ?

```
try:
    COMMAND_1
except 2:
    COMMAND_2
except 3:
    COMMAND_3
except:
    print("Ошибка")
```

(если команда 1 не выполнена перейти к выполнению 2, если 2, перейти к 3, если 3 перейти к except)

очень не хочется писать заборчиком...

```
try:
    try:
        COMMAND_1
    except:
        try:
            COMMAND_2
        except:
            COMMAND_3
except:
    print("Ошибка")
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста пример, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Поправил, надуюсь более понятно...

Comment: Если команда не выполнилась, то выбросит исключение?

Comment: ну да, если выполнилась - дальнейший код (который здесь не указан), если не выполнилась, следующая команда.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример `COMMAND_1` и какие ошибки вы можете ожидать при ее выполнении?